# A moment of multinomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, multinomial-distribution

Assume $x_1, \dots, x_k$ are distributed according to a multinomial distribution with parameters $n, p_1, \dots, p_k$. How can I compute the following expectation or a non-trivial upper bound for it?

$$ \mathbb{E} \Big[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_i}}\;  \Big| \; x_i > 0 \Big]$$

Comment: If $X_i$ inside the expectation is just one of the marginal, univariate random variable, then $X_i \sim \text{Binomial}(n, p_i)$ and thus $\displaystyle \mathbb{E}\left[\frac {1} {\sqrt{X_i}} \mid X_i > 0 \right] = \frac {1} {\mathbb{P}\{X_i > 0\}} \sum_{x=1}^n \frac {1} {\sqrt{x}} \binom {n} {x} p_i^x (1-p_i)^{n-x}$